# unique number from 3D coordinates

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory, coordinate-systems

Is it possible to get a unique real number from $(x,y,z)$ coordinates? I need to sort a list of coordinates so i am looking for a simple function that generates one unique number with which to sort. It doesn't have to work all the time but something that works most of the time. First thing I thought was $x^2+y^2+z^2$ but then it fails for all points on a sphere so i have now $x^2+y^2+z^2+x-y+2z$ which i can't think of an example to make it fail. $x,y,z$ could at most be radius of the earth 6870000m.

Comment: You could just go with lexicographic ordering ie $(x, y, z) < (x', y', z')$ iff $x < x'$ or $x=x'$ and $y<y'$ or $x=x'$, $y=y'$ and $z<z'$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll assume that you want a function $f: \mathbb{R}^3 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ that is [injective](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Injective_function).

This is a bit messy - there is probably a better way to do this, but here goes. Let your inputs for $f$ be

$$x = a_na_{n-1}a_{n-2}\cdots a_2a_1.b_1b_2b_3\cdots$$

$$y = c_nc_{n-1}c_{n-2}\cdots c_2c_1.d_1d_2d_3\cdots$$

$$z = e_ne_{n-1}e_{n-2}\cdots e_2e_1.f_1f_2f_3\cdots$$

The decimal points are between $a_1$ and $b_1$, $c_1$ and $d_1$, and $e_1$ and $f_1$. We allow leading zeroes and simply take $n$ to be the number of digits of the maximum of $\lfloor x \rfloor$, $\lfloor y \rfloor$, and $\lfloor z \rfloor$.

Then we let $$f(x,y,z)=a_nc_ne_na_{n-1}c_{n-1}e_{n-1}\cdots a_1c_1e_1.b_1d_1f_1b_2d_2f_2\cdots$$

This function is injective. It also satisfies $$f(x,y,z) < 10^{3n}$$

Comment: I am sure you are correct but i am looking for something more practical for a computer implementation. if I do 2^6870000 (i.e radius of the earth), it would be infinity.

Comment: @danny I never used powers of $2$ - I think maybe you meant to reply to the other answer?

Comment: Sorry, yes i meant to post to the other answer @gamamal

Answer (score 1):

You need an injective function from $\mathbb R^3$ to $\mathbb R$ You can take the following: Given $x,y,z$ take the decimal representation (if there are two take the finite one). And send $(x,y,z)$ to the following number: The part of the number before the decimal is going to be $2^{\lfloor{x}\rfloor}3^{\lfloor{y}\rfloor}5^{\lfloor{z}\rfloor}$ and the part after the decimal is going to be constructed by alternating $x,y$ and $z$.

Suppose $x$ has the following decimal expansion after the decimal: $.x_1x_2x_3\dots$

$y$ has $.y_1y_2y_3\dots $ and $z$ has $.z_1z_2z_3\dots$

Then we send $(x,y,x)$ to $2^{\lfloor{x}\rfloor}3^{\lfloor{y}\rfloor}5^{\lfloor{z}\rfloor}+.x_1y_1z_1x_2y_2z_2x_3y_3z_3x_4y_4z_4\dots$

Comment: Nice answer, +1. We had a similar thought process - I think what you did with the non-decimal part is more elegant.

Comment: Yes, it seems similar. +1 to you too.

Answer (score 0):

[Zubin's answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1312687/1206794) is not [injective](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Injective_function) since the signs of $x$, $y$, and $z$ are not accounted for. See the bottom of this answer for why.

Instead, to make the solution fully injective, do as Zubin suggests, but also encode the signs in the lowest digits of the output number:

Let your inputs for $f$ be

$$
x = s_xa_na_{n-1}a_{n-2}\cdots a_2a_1.b_1b_2b_3\cdots \\
y = s_yc_nc_{n-1}c_{n-2}\cdots c_2c_1.d_1d_2d_3\cdots \\
z = s_ze_ne_{n-1}e_{n-2}\cdots e_2e_1.f_1f_2f_3\cdots
$$

where

$$
s_x = \operatorname{sgn}(x) \\
s_y = \operatorname{sgn}(y) \\
s_z = \operatorname{sgn}(z) \\
n = \max(
    \operatorname{digits}(\lfloor x \rfloor),
    \operatorname{digits}(\lfloor y \rfloor),
    \operatorname{digits}(\lfloor z \rfloor))
$$

Now, let us find the value $v$ resulting from encoding the signs as binary flags:

$$
u_x = \frac{(1 - s_x)}{2}  = \begin{cases}
    0 & \text{if } s_x = 1 \\
    1 & \text{if } s_x = -1
\end{cases}\\
u_y = 1 - s_y = \begin{cases}
    0 & \text{if } s_y = 1 \\
    2 & \text{if } s_y = -1
\end{cases} \\
u_z = 2(1 - s_x) = \begin{cases}
    0 & \text{if } s_z = 1 \\
    4 & \text{if } s_z = -1
\end{cases} \\
v = u_x + u_y + u_z = 3.5 - \frac{s_x}{2} - s_y - 2s_z
$$

As with Zubin's answer, the decimal points are between $a_1$ and $b_1$, $c_1$ and $d_1$, and $e_1$ and $f_1$. Interleave $x$, $y$, and $z$, replacing any non-existent digits with zeroes and inserting $v$ between $e_1$ and the decimal point:

$$f(x,y,z)=a_nc_ne_na_{n-1}c_{n-1}e_{n-1}\cdots a_1c_1e_1v.b_1d_1f_1b_2d_2f_2\cdots$$

Here is a Python implementation:

```
import typing

'''
Call like this:
`collapse_to_text(["1", "2", "3"])`
`collapse_to_text(["1.2", "3.45", "678.9"])`
`collapse_to_text(["-2.62", "51.901", "-9978.43"])`

Supports any dimensions. Not just 3D. For a 5D vector, call like this:
`collapse_to_text(["-2.62", "51.901", "-9978.43", "-1098572.4953085", "-0.2"])`
'''
def collapse_to_text(strings: typing.List[str]) -> str:
    for index in range(len(strings)):
        strings[index] = str(float(strings[index]))
    # Find max digits for binary representation of negatives
    max_value_of_signs_as_binary = 2**len(strings) - 1
    decimal_digits_of_negatives = len(str(max_value_of_signs_as_binary))
    # Get value of binary representation of negatives
    negative_digits = 0
    power_of_two = 1
    for string in strings:
        negative_digits += power_of_two if string.startswith("-") else 0
        power_of_two *= 2
    # Split the strings by their decimal points
    lefts = []
    rights = []
    max_length_l = 0
    max_length_r = 0
    for string in strings:
        split = string.lstrip("-").split(".")
        lefts.append(split[0])
        # The number may not have any digits after a decimal point
        rights.append(split[1] if len(split) > 1 else "")
        # Find the longest of the digit strings before the decimal point
        max_length_l = max(max_length_l, len(lefts[-1]))
        # Find the longest of the digit strings after the decimal point
        max_length_r = max(max_length_r, len(rights[-1]))
    for index in range(len(strings)):
        # Pad the left segments to be the same length, starting with zeros
        lefts[index] = lefts[index].rjust(max_length_l, "0")
        # Pad the right segments to be the same length, ending with zeros
        rights[index] = rights[index].ljust(max_length_r, "0")
    combination = ""
    # Zip the digits to the left of the decimal places in the strings
    for index in range(max_length_l):
        for left in lefts:
            if len(combination) == 0 and left[index] == "0":
                continue
            combination += left[index]
    # Insert the digits representing the signs of the different values
    combination += str(negative_digits).rjust(decimal_digits_of_negatives, "0")
    # Insert the decimal point between the sign digits and zipped right digits 
    combination += "."
    # Zip the digits to the right of the decimal places in the strings
    for index in range(max_length_r):
        for right in rights:
            combination += right[index]
    # Remove trailing zeros from the resulting number
    combination = combination.rstrip("0")
    # Remove the decimal point if it has no digits after it
    combination = combination.rstrip(".")
    return combination

print(collapse_to_text(["1.2", "3.4", "5.6"]))
print(collapse_to_text(["-1.2", "3.4", "5.6"]))
print(collapse_to_text(["1.2", "-3.4", "5.6"]))
print(collapse_to_text(["-1.2", "-3.4", "5.6"]))
print(collapse_to_text(["1.2", "3.4", "-5.6"]))
print(collapse_to_text(["-1.2", "3.4", "-5.6"]))
print(collapse_to_text(["1.2", "-3.4", "-5.6"]))
print(collapse_to_text(["-1.2", "-3.4", "-5.6"]))
print(collapse_to_text(["1", "2", "3"]))
print(collapse_to_text(["1.2", "3.45", "678.9"]))
print(collapse_to_text(["-2.62", "51.901", "-9978.43"]))
print(collapse_to_text(["-2.62", "51.901", "-9978.43", "-1098572.4953085", "-0.2"]))
```

With output:

```
1350.246
1351.246
1352.246
1353.246
1354.246
1355.246
1356.246
1357.246
1230
60071380.24905
90090572185.69420301
1000000000900098000950057702182029.6944220390010500003000000000800005
```

You can see in the above result's first 8 tests, the one's digits are interleaved, followed by the encoded signs of the input numbers, followed by the decimal point, and finally followed by the interleaved tenth's digits.

The last 4 tests do the same thing, but with more complex test cases.

And here is a Python implementation that will perform the inverse operation:

```
import typing

'''
Call like this:
`expand_from_text("1230", ["", "", ""])`
`expand_from_text("1360070080.040259", ["", "", ""])`
`expand_from_text("2590190070085.090604213", ["", "", ""])`

Supports any dimensions. Not just 3D. For a 5D vector, call like this:
`expand_from_text("2591001900007900088000050000700002029.00040000900005000030090006048021352", ["", "", "", "", ""])`
'''
def expand_from_text(s: str, strings: typing.List[str]):
    dimensions = len(strings)
    for index in range(dimensions):
        strings[index] = ""
    split = s.split(".")
    if len(split) < 2: split.append("")
    # Find max digits for binary representation of negatives
    max_value_of_signs_as_binary = 2**dimensions - 1
    decimal_digits_of_negatives = len(str(max_value_of_signs_as_binary))
    negative_digits = int(split[0][-decimal_digits_of_negatives:])
    # Get negatives from value of their binary representation
    power_of_two = 1
    for index in range(dimensions):
        strings[index] += "-" if ((negative_digits & power_of_two) == power_of_two) else ""
        power_of_two *= 2
    # Remove digits for negatives from digits to left of decimal point
    split[0] = split[0][:-decimal_digits_of_negatives]
    # Get digits from left of decimal point
    if len(split[0]) < 1:
        for index in range(dimensions):
            strings[index] += "0"
    for index in range(len(split[0])):
        # The leftmost digit of the source string may not be for the leftmost dimension
        descending_index = len(split[0]) - (index + 1)
        descending_dimension = descending_index % dimensions
        ascending_dimension = dimensions - (descending_dimension + 1)
        # Ignore leading zeros for each dimension unless it's the ones digit
        is_zero = split[0][index] == "0"
        is_empty = len(strings[ascending_dimension]) == 0
        is_ones_digit = descending_index < dimensions
        if is_zero and not is_ones_digit:
            if is_empty:
                continue
            has_no_digits = strings[ascending_dimension][-1] == "-"
            if has_no_digits:
                continue
        strings[ascending_dimension] += split[0][index]
    # Add in decimal point if there are decimal places
    if len(split[1]) > 0:
        for index in range(dimensions):
            strings[index] += "."
    # Get digits from right of decimal point
    for index in range(len(split[1])):
        strings[index % dimensions] += split[1][index]
    # Remove trailing zeros and decimal places if there are decimal places
    if len(split[1]) > 0:
        for index in range(dimensions):
            # Remove trailing zeros from the resulting number
            strings[index] = strings[index].rstrip("0")
            # Remove the decimal point if it has no digits after it
            strings[index] = strings[index].rstrip(".")

def test(s: str, strings: typing.List[str]):
    expand_from_text(s, strings)
    print(strings)

test("1350.246", ["", "", ""])
test("1351.246", ["", "", ""])
test("1352.246", ["", "", ""])
test("1353.246", ["", "", ""])
test("1354.246", ["", "", ""])
test("1355.246", ["", "", ""])
test("1356.246", ["", "", ""])
test("1357.246", ["", "", ""])
test("1230", ["", "", ""])
test("60071380.24905", ["", "", ""])
test("90090572185.69420301", ["", "", ""])
test("1000000000900098000950057702182029.6944220390010500003000000000800005", ["", "", "", "", ""])
```

With output:

```
['1.2', '3.4', '5.6']
['-1.2', '3.4', '5.6']
['1.2', '-3.4', '5.6']
['-1.2', '-3.4', '5.6']
['1.2', '3.4', '-5.6']
['-1.2', '3.4', '-5.6']
['1.2', '-3.4', '-5.6']
['-1.2', '-3.4', '-5.6']
['1', '2', '3']
['1.2', '3.45', '678.9']
['-2.62', '51.901', '-9978.43']
['-2.62', '51.901', '-9978.43', '-1098572.4953085', '-0.2']
```

Notes on the implementation:

- $-0$ collapses to $1$, which then expands to $-0$, preserving the negative, even though $0$ and $-0$ are mathematically equal
- In expansion, leading zeros are trimmed, as are trailing zeros, so $001.0$ collapses to $10$, which then expands to $1$

---

Why do the signs of $x$, $y$, and $z$ cause problems for [Zubin's answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1312687/1206794)? It is only [injective](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Injective_function) if $x$, $y$, and $z$ have artificial limits placed on their signs. For example if they are guaranteed to always share the same sign, either all being positive or all being negative.

Zubin doesn't mention negatives, but regardless of what method you might use to resolve the negatives, you need more than just a single negative sign to preserve the data of three negative signs. Thus Zubin's method is incomplete. My method merely builds on Zubin's to make it fully injective.

Here are two ways you might try to resolve the three signs to a single sign in Zubin's method that don't work and example inputs showing why they don't work:

- If negative digits are resolved by subtraction, then rollover will cause shared outputs by different inputs:

$$f(0,0,5)=100(0)+10(0)+1(5)=5$$
$$f(0,1,-5)=100(0)+10(1)+1(-5)=10-5=5$$
$$\therefore f(0,0,5)=f(0,1,-5)$$

- Otherwise, if negative digits are treated as positive and the axis as a whole negates the result, then double and triple negation cause shared outputs by different inputs:

$$f(-3,4,5)=\operatorname{sgn}(-3)\operatorname{sgn}(4)\operatorname{sgn}(5)(100|-3|+10|4|+1|5|)=(-1)(1)(1)(100(3)+10(4)+1(5))=(-1)(300+40+5)=-345$$
$$f(-3,-4,-5)=\operatorname{sgn}(-3)\operatorname{sgn}(-4)\operatorname{sgn}(-5)(100|-3|+10|-4|+1|-5|)=(-1)(-1)(-1)(100(3)+10(4)+1(5))=(-1)(300+40+5)=-345$$
$$\therefore f(-3,4,5)=f(-3,-4,-5)$$